# Why this code display only 3 entries? WP

Tags: wordpress

I created a template category-beers.php which should display all posts from single category. All posts should display in table. Everything works good, but this code display only 3 recent posts. What should I edit, to display all posts from this category?

```
<table class="drinked-beers">
<tr>
<th>Beer</th>
<th>Consumer</th>
<th>I drinked this beer on </th>
<th>Style</th>
<th>Note</th>

</tr>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<tr>
<td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
<td><?php the_author(); ?></td>
<td><?php the_date(''); ?> </td>
<td><?php the_tags(''); ?> </td>
<td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my-note', true); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your number of posts set to 3? Go into `Settings->Reading` to check

Comment: Yes. But I need to display 3 posts on my home page. Can I set in above code to display all posts?

Comment: Is that the only code for the page? is there no more?

Comment: This is the hole loop for this category.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but i think it will achieve what you're looking for.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
$args = array( 'category' => $category_id, 'post_type' =>  'post' , 'numberposts'=>-1); 
$posts = get_posts( $args );    
foreach ($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);?>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
        <td><?php the_author(); ?></td>
        <td><?php the_date(''); ?> </td>
        <td><?php the_tags(''); ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my-note', true); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```